# Not able to add image in a DataTable in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I am struck up with a peculiar problem wherein I want to add an image that is there in my `Resources` folder in my `WPF` solution. I am getting the image path instead of the image name `(../../Resources/Excel.png)`. I have tried so many things like converting `image` to `Byte[]` but it doesnt seem to work. Here is my code.

```
 public DataTable BDU_DtmDcmDfmSelect(string Tablename)
        {


            DataTable tableData = new DataTable();
            tableData = dal.DAL_BDU_DtmDcmDfmSelect(Tablename);

            // All filter column in list
            List<String> FilterColumns = new List<string>();
            FilterColumns.Add("INS_DTE"); FilterColumns.Add("UPDD_DTE");
            FilterColumns.Add("DEL_DTE"); FilterColumns.Add("INSD_BY");
            FilterColumns.Add("UPDD_BY"); FilterColumns.Add("DELD_BY");

            // Reading all table column to a list as can not run loop when removing
            List<String> TableColumns = new List<string>();
            foreach (var text in tableData.Columns)
            {
                TableColumns.Add(text.ToString());
            }

            // Running loop by comparing the both the column to avoid exception
            foreach (string tablecol in TableColumns)
            {
                foreach (string filtercol in FilterColumns)
                {
                    if (tablecol == filtercol)
                    {
                        tableData.Columns.Remove(filtercol);
                    }
                }

            }

            //tableData.Columns.Add("Edit", typeof(bool)) ;
            //tableData.Columns.Add("Delete" ,typeof(bool));

            //DataColumn workCol = tableData.Columns.Add("CustID", typeof(int));

            //for (int i = 0; i < tableData.Columns.Count; i++)
            //{
            //    if (i == (tableData.Columns.Count-1))
            //    {
            //        for (int j = 0; j < tableData.Rows.Count; j++)
            //        {
            //            tableData.Rows[j][i] = 5;
            //        }

            //    }
            //}


            tableData.Columns.Add("EditImage", typeof(BitmapImage));

             BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../Resources/Excel.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

            // ;
           /// Image img = new Image();

            //img.Source = @"../../Resources/Excel.png";
            for (int i = 0; i < tableData.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == (tableData.Columns.Count - 1))
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < tableData.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                         tableData.Rows[j][i] = image;
                    }

                }
            }

            tableData.Columns.Add("EditImage1", typeof(Image));

            Button btn = new Button();

            btn.Content = "Edit";
            btn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(200, 233, 222, 100));

            for (int i = 0; i < tableData.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == (tableData.Columns.Count - 1))
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < tableData.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        tableData.Rows[j][i] = btn;
                    }

                }
            }


            //DataColumn imagecol = new DataColumn();
            //tableData.Columns.Add(imagecol);
            //DataColumn imagecol1 = new DataColumn();
            //imagecol1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]");




            return tableData;
        }
```

The above method has been called and the output has been assigned to a `GridView`

```
 public void displayTableData(String TableName)
        {

            var TableName1 = CmbMasterTable.SelectedItem.ToString();
            var Tablename2 = CmbMasterTable.SelectedValue.ToString();
            var Tablename3 = CmbMasterTable.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TableName))
            {
                DisplayGrid.ItemsSource = dcobj.BDU_DtmDcmDfmSelect(TableName).DefaultView;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TableName1))
            {
                DisplayGrid.ItemsSource = dcobj.BDU_DtmDcmDfmSelect(TableName1).DefaultView;
            }
        }
```

The specific `XAML` would be

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="DisplayGrid" Grid.Row ="1" >

                    </DataGrid>
```

Please assist.

Comment: You are adding a button to the DataTable not an image : tableData.Columns.Add("EditImage1", typeof(Button));  So you want to display the image or only store the image?

Comment: @jdweng no actually its the first one. Please check the code above this line

Comment: Where are you intending to display the image?

Comment: @mm8 tableData.Columns.Add("EditImage", typeof(BitmapImage));

Comment: @mm8 its later assigned to a GridView. Let me share the screenshot

Comment: @Apoorv no screenshots please. They don't compile nor do they show what settings, code, bindings were used. Post the *code* and XAML markup. Since your question is about *displaying* a DataTable, the code posted here doesn't help - unless `BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../Resources/Excel.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));` fails to load the image, which is quite possible

Comment: @Apoorv: A `DataGrid` doesn't know how to render a `DataColumn` with a of type `BitmapImage`. You need to use a converter or a template to display it.

Comment: @mm8 I tried to convert the image into byte[] stream didnt work. Even I tried using Image(System.Windows.Control) and it dint work. Would you be able to provide a solution?

Comment: @Apoorv: Sure, if you post your XAML or at least show *how* you use the `DataTable`.

Comment: @mm8 just updated it. One line of XAML

Comment: What type database supports typeof(BitmapImage)?  Saving data as byte[] should work and if it doesn't you should find out why.  Stay focus on real issues and don't just keeping on changing code when a a method that should work fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataGrid` doesn't know how to render a `DataColumn` with a of type `Image`. You need to use a converter or a template to be able to display it:

```
DisplayGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += (s, e) =>
{
    const string Xaml = "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><ContentControl Content=\"{{Binding {0}}}\" /></DataTemplate>";
    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(Image))
    {
        DataGridTemplateColumn tc = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        tc.CellTemplate = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(string.Format(Xaml, e.PropertyName)) as DataTemplate;
        e.Column = tc;
    }
};
```

Comment: where should I add this piece?

Comment: In the code-behind of the view where the `DataGrid` is defined.

Comment: Do i need to change something else also? Like changing the ColumnType from BitmapImage to Image ?

Comment: Yes, the `ColumnType` should be `Image` and the value should be set an `Image` for my sample code to work as expected.

Comment: got an error "Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <../../Resources/Excel.png> in EditImage Column.  Expected type is Image."

Comment: possible for you to modify my code above for a specific column so that I can learn? I have changed the ColumnType to Image but the error above

Comment: Once again, you need to set the cell to an image: `tableData.Rows[j][i] = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../Resources/Excel.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) };`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192044/discussion-between-apoorv-and-mm8).